# behavior of or condition in boolean indexing pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is the 'or' portion of my attempt to grab values from a df. What I'd like it to do is get the values when the first part of the condition if true, and if not, grab the values from the second part of the condition. That doesn't seem to be happening as the order appears to have no impact on the changes to my df.

```
(df[colA] == row[colA]-1) | (df[colA] == row[colA]-2)
```

What is actually happening and is there a way to get the information I want?

Edit: The or condition is one of several boolean conditions and part of a larger function. But the A column here illustrates my problem. I need to go back one, and if there is no A that matches minus 1, get the values from two back. I've used the same code and function for grabbing values one row back and it works fine when there aren't gaps.

```
A  B
1  x
2  y
3  z
5  aa
6  bb
```

Here's a better example. This would be similar to the array I'm using to get values for the function that alters the df. I can't figure out

a.) how it's determining whether the values will be from one or two rows displaced

b.) how to write the code so I can default to one when true and only go two rows when one isn't true

```
values=df_bkp[(df_bkp['B']==row['B'])&((df_bkp['A']==row['A']-1)|(df_bkp['A']==row['A']-2))][col].values
```

I understand where the values are coming from when I do this:

```
values=df_bkp[(df_bkp['B']==row['B'])&(df_bkp['A']==row['A']-1)][col].values
```

Comment: Can you please post some example input and output? It's hard to tell exactly how this should look.

Comment: You already have b): `False or True` equals `True`, `True or False` equals `True`

Comment: @hellpanderrr are you implying that my first values formula should give me different results depending on which side i place the conditions in the or statement? i'm getting the same thing regardless of order: the values from rows that are 2 less even when there is a value from a row that is one less

Comment: Could you post some examples with your actual data?

Answer (score 0):

`df[colA] == row[colA]-1`

This compares two columns element-by-element and results in a boolean column like

```
True
True
False
True
...
```

Same for the right part, so after these two operations you get two boolean vectors, e.g.:

```
True        True
True        False
False       True
True        True
...         ...
```

The `|` operator does element-by-element comparison of these two vectors:

```
True   or   True    =   True
True   or   False   =   True
False  or   True    =   True
True   or   True    =   True
...    or   ...     =   ...
```

Comment: but what value does it grab when indexing? in other words, if i'm just testing one side i'll get the value corresponding to that row if true. since both sides could be true and one of them is always true, which row's values will be selected?

Comment: You need to expand your example, I can't grasp it like that. When you do indexing, you insert a boolean vector into the dataframe and it returns rows where the vector has the `True` value.

Comment: added better example. i think.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you may be using the incorrect "or" operator. In Python it is just "or"

```
((df[colA] == row[colA]) or (df[colA] == row[colA]-1)
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, since this is a `pandas` question, the objects are columns/vectors of values and you use the `|` or operator to do element-by-element comparisons.